Jquery ajax call set value to product attribute not saved in magento2
I created product attributes based on the selection of attribute yes/no I am calling Ajax to get value and set it in the editor custom attributes but after setting value by jQuery and saving the product it's not saving.
If the shipping exception is no

If shipping exception yes I am setting the content to the shipping charges attribute but it is not saved. only after clicking on that editor is it saved

CODE
<script>
    require(
        ['jquery','tinymce'],
        function ($,tinymce) {
            var ajaxurl = '<?php echo $block->getAjaxUrl() ?>';

            $(document).on('keyup change', '[name="product[shipping_exception]"]', function () {
                var productType = $('[name="product[product_type]"]').val();
                var shippingException = $('[name="product[shipping_exception]"]').val();
                if (shippingException == 1) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: ajaxurl,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: ({
                            product_type: productType
                        }),
                        //showLoader: true,
                        success: function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                            if (response.status == 200) {
                                var data = response.data;
                                tinymce.get('product_form_pan_shipping_charges').setContent(data.shipping_charges);
                                tinymce.get('product_form_pan_shipping_info').setContent(data.shipping_info);
                                tinymce.get('product_form_pan_terms_of_sale').setContent(data.terms_of_sale);
                            } else {
                                tinymce.get('product_form_pan_shipping_charges').setContent('');
                                tinymce.get('product_form_pan_shipping_info').setContent('');
                                tinymce.get('product_form_pan_terms_of_sale').setContent('');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        }); 
</script>

Please help me why it's not saved anything is missing to add.
your help will be appreciated

can you explain in more details what you are trying to achieve?

after selection of ye/no attribute. if yes I am calling one ajax to get data and set the value to the editor attribute. above code is working to call ajax and set value to editor but after saved product is not saved

before save product if i click that editor its saved

because of editor is triggered

Before setting the value to the editor attribute field focus editor.
tinymce.get('product_form_pan_shipping_charges').focus();
tinymce.get('product_form_pan_shipping_charges').setContent(data.shipping_charges);


If you are using Jquery, then you need to try like this.
$("textarea[name='product[shipping_charges]']").val(data.shipping_charges);


its not working. i already tried
